# Which Hex code for /boot partition

Tags: arch-linux, boot, partition, hex

I planned to install ArchLinux on my laptop. I'm only at the begining, trying to understand all the step before doing them. I'm only at the first step, i.e. partitioning, that I already have a small problem. I want to use my SSD as Raid0.

My laptop uses UEFI boot so I have GPT table. To create the raid0, I have understood that I need to create one partition on each drive, then use `mdadm` to create the raid. However, before doing this, I need to create a partition for /boot. I have read that the size of this partition must be 300 MB. Is it true?

My second question is about the hex code I've to use. I've seen that there is a code ef00 for EFI System, but also a code for MBR partition scheme and one for BIOS boot partition. I suppose that I have to use ef00. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

ef00 is the correct code for UEFI boot partition.

The size does not *have* to be 300MB, I would say at least 100MB. I generally use 512MB for no real reason other than it is large enough that I don't need to care and I like the number. It only has to be as large and the kernels and configs you store in it (with some room to spare). Mine currently uses 36MB on one of computers and 26MB on another so plenty of space.

Comment: As a counter example, I usually set up 500mb boot partitions and they frequently fill up. If you are on a fast moving distro and/or use debug kernels (development), a 30 mb boot partition would be completely undersized.

Comment: @Argonauts: Archlinux does a replacement of the kernel rather installing a new kernel alongside the old one (for better or worse) so tends to not suffer from the boot partition filling up despite being a fast moving distro. But you are right it 30MB is way to small for the partition, its just the size of the used space on my /boot (with archlinux).

Answer (score 1):

ef00 appears to be the correct hex code.